# Sudden influx of similar types of questions with grammatical and formatting errors

Tags: discussion, contests, exams

There have been 3 recent posts in the span of around 10 minutes with generally the same types of questions all coming from low score accounts.

[the length of a perpendicular inside of a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4102464/the-lenght-of-a-perpendicular-inside-of-a-triangle)

[Adding trisector vectors on an equilateral triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4102449/a-geometry-problem-with-a-trangle)

and this one which is seemingly unrelated but also has the formatting errors and 2021 in the problem

[Recursive sum, boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4102445/recursive-sum-boundary)

I think these posts deserve a look into, they might probably be exam questions or contest questions.

Comment: That 3rd question seems to have been posted multiple times. Other users have posted links in the comments.

Comment: How did you conclude the accounts were from India tho? I checked the account in second  and third post and they havent filled in location

Comment: I think it is entirely inappropriate for a user to have concluded that.  I edited the post.  The OP may roll back my edit, however, in which case I think the post is worthy of a flag.

Comment: @amWhy I apologize for the assumption, the last post was by an Indian account and they all occurred within the same time frame and so I assumed it must be it, there was no malicious intent behind my assumption I myself am Indian.

Comment: I appreciate your clarification, Filthyscrub. We all need to be careful whether what we say or assume may be seen as offensive, even when speaking with the best of intentions.  I do trust that you had no "malicious intent".  Cheers!